# Execution Timed Out (12000 ms): How can I optimize this function?

Tags: python, function, optimization, integer

I need to write this function for a Kata on Codewars, which takes a positive integer as a parameter and find the next smaller number with the same digits. So for example if I would input `next_smaller(2071)` then I would expect to get `2017`.

Here's what I have so far, and it works just fine, but I get a timeout error for longer integers, I tried finding ways to optimize it, but they don't really work, thank you very much in advance.

```
from itertools import permutations
def next_smaller(n):
    l = sorted([''.join(i) for i in permutations(str(n))],reverse=True)
    for i in l:
        if i[0]!='0':
            if int(i)<n:
                return int(i)
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be faster than your solution. I think it should be:

```
def next_smaller(x):
    foo = [int(''.join(i)) for i in permutations(x) if int(''.join(i)) < int(x)]
    foo.sort()
    
    try:
        return foo[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

I guess, you're getting slowed down significantly by both the explicit `for` cycles and `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working:

```
from collections import Counter
def next_smaller(num):
    sorted_str_num=[]
    str_num = [num for num in str(num)]
    
    zero_count = Counter(str_num)['0']
    sorted_str_num = sorted(str_num)[zero_count:]
    index = 0
    for i in reversed(range(len(str_num)-1)):
                index +=1
                if str_num[i] > str_num[i+1]:
                    str_num[i], str_num[i+1] = str_num[i+1], str_num[i]
                    break
    if str_num == [num for num in str(num)] or index == len(str_num)-1:
        return f"this is lowest {len(str_num)} digit number with these {str_num}"
    
    if str_num != [num for num in str(num)] and str_num[0] != '0':
        return int("".join(str_num))
    
    else:
        if zero_count:
            min_num= (sorted_str_num.pop(0))
            result =([min_num] + sorted(sorted_str_num+ ['0']*zero_count,reverse=True))
            return int("".join(result))
        else:
            min_num= (sorted_str_num.pop(0))
            result =([min_num] + sorted(sorted_str_num,reverse=True))
            return  int("".join(result))          

print(next_smaller(2071))
print(next_smaller(15406))
print(next_smaller(1001))
print(next_smaller(2345))

2017
15046
this is lowest 4 digit number with these ['0', '1', '0', '1']
this is lowest 4 digit number with these ['2', '3', '4', '5']
```